# generate time series dataframe based on a given dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

There is a dataframe,  which includes one column of `time` and another column of `bill`. As can be seen from the table, there can have multiple records for a single day. The order of `time` can be random

```
time                              bill
2006-1-18                          10.11
2006-1-18                          9.02
2006-1-19                          12.34
2006-1-20                          6.86
2006-1-12                          10.05
```

Based on these information, I would like to generate a time series dataframe, which has two columns `Time`  and  `total bill`

The time column will save the date in order, the total bill will save the sum of multiple bill records belonging to one day.

Comment: df.groupby('Time').bill.sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('time').bill.sum())
newdf.rename(columns={'time':'Time', 'bill': 'total bill'}, inplace = True)
newdf
```

output:

```
    Time    total_bill
0   2006-1-18   10.11
1   2006-1-18   9.02
2   2006-1-19   12.34
3   2006-1-20   6.86
4   2006-1-12   10.05
```